# LINQ to Entities query of tests for my classes, with many subqueries

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This MVC4 controller method, which uses EF6, is taking a long time to run (over 2 seconds). I've added verbose comments for the purpose of this post only.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  // Get a list of all the classes I teach.
  var myClasses = await CurrentUser.GetClassesAsync(db);

  // Get a list of all tests...
  var tests = await db.Tests
    // Which are either authored by me or involve one of my classes...
    .Where(o => o.AuthorId == CurrentUser.Id || (o.Author.SchoolId == CurrentUser.SchoolId && o.Classes.Any(c => myClasses.Contains(c.ClassName))))
    // And for each one I want...
    .Select(o => new TestOverviewItem
    {
      // The ID, title and test status
      Id = o.Id,
      Title = o.Title,
      Status = o.Status,
      // A list of which of my classes are registered for the test
      Classes = o.Classes.Where(c => myClasses.Contains(c.ClassName)).Select(c => c.ClassName).ToList(),
      // An indication of whether any results exist for students in my classes
      AnyUploads = o.Results.Any(r => r.User.Classes.Any(c => myClasses.Contains(c.ClassName))),
      // How many unmarked results there are for students in my classes
      RemainingToMark = o.Results.Count(r => r.MarkedBy == null && r.QuestionNumber > 0 && r.User.Classes.Any(c => myClasses.Contains(c.ClassName))),
      // An indication of whether I created the test
      IsOwner = o.AuthorId == CurrentUser.Id
    })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ToListAsync();
  return View("Index", new OverviewModel(CurrentUser, tests, myClasses));
}
```

There are about 50 tests in total which match the criteria, and each one has ~4 `Classes` and ~2000 `Results`. I understand that all the subqueries must be slowing it down, but I'm not sure how to optimise.

Comment: Where is `classes` defined? Can you leave out the `.ToList()` where you populate `Classes`?

Comment: It should have said `myClasses`. `TestOverviewItem.Classes` is defined as an `IList` which is why `.ToList()` is there. Could be changed if it would make a difference though.

Comment: Well it depends on how the code is used but typically a `.ToList()` call triggers execution of the query though I'm not sure if it will actually have an effect here.

Answer (score 2):

I bet the database does not have the indexes to process this combination of conditions, especially with a contains on a name column. You will get table scans. Break off the `|| (o.Author.SchoolId == CurrentUser.SchoolId...` part to return a new list of `AuthorIds` and you can add the `CurrentUser.Id` so the `db.Tests` where condition is just using the primary key.

The idea here is to preprocess your contains to be lists of ints to make the indexes happy.